# Ungroup user menu in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6.x with Zen theme.

Currently, the following 3 user functions are grouped under a menu, when accessing urls like http://domain.com/user

> Create new account / Log in / Request
>   new password

How can I un-group them so that each of them can still be accessed via its original url; while removing/ supressing the menu carrying the 3 items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution would be to change them with [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu_alter/6) and make them into MENU_NORMAL_ITEM instead of MENU_LOCAL_TASK.

Alternative, you could change the output through theming, but this is probably less simple to achieve.